# Symfony 2 API authentication method

Tags: api, symfony, oauth

I have a JSON REST API written in Symfony 2.7, and I want to authenticate & authorize users. This is my first time doing this, so I have some doubts/questions.

For that, I thought several methods:

1. User & password, and then save a session in the back end
2. Same as 1), but add an "apiToken" (randomly generate when user register) and then sending back & forth the apiToken in every single request to check user identity.
3. Use OAuth (which I'm currently reading about it).

I read that using OAuth for a simple API is like an "overkill", but on the safe side it sticks to standards and also allows me to use it when using my API with mobile devices and different platforms.

Also, I don't know too much about security flaws of using method 1) or 2).

I know this is maybe based on opinions, but I don't know any other site to post this question, as Symfony official mailing was shut down and migrate here it seems.

Answer (score 0):

As you seems to know, your question is too opinion based.

If I can give you some advices (too long for a 600chars comment),

OAuth is powerful, but so much free.
I mean that you can easily implement it sort as everything works well while having a set of potential security issues without being aware of their existence.

Libraries and bundles providing OAuth are hard to maintain because of the new security issues regularly found.
On the other hand, if you need the benefits of OAuth (be a client and/or a server, compatible with the most part of social networks), go learn OAuth and do your experience with it.

Otherwise, use a simple credentials/request token two-step authentication.

See the [JWT Authentication tutorial by KnpLabs](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony-rest4),
[Symfony Guard Authentication by Ryan Weaver](http://Symfony%20Guard%20Authentication:%20Fun%20with%20API%20Token,%20Social%20Login,%20JWT%20and%20more),
and the great [LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle), easy to implement and to use.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm started using Guard, but no idea if was a correct approach.